# "ctrl + c" is not recognising while bootup in RHEL 6

Tags: python

Seems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is not recognising .While I run in terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> is recognised and its going to signal handler function as expected .
but when script is run as boot script it should recognise <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and enter 
the signal handler ,but its not happening .here is part of script ..

```
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Going to Linux terminal....'
    sys.exit(0)
print 'Press Ctrl+C to abort script and enter Linux terminal....'
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
time.sleep(5)
```

Script is working proper ,but the problem is its not getting the terminal.
ssh to the termianl is possible ,

Thanks in advance

Comment: uhmm… the OS hasn't booted up yet, during bootup and you need an OS for python to run

Answer (score 2):

When you receive the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> event in you script, your script will just terminate itself. It will *not* terminate the whole boot sequence.

Checking a boot-script that *does* exit to a shell (the script that checks the disks with the `fsck` command) you will see something like this:

```
# Start a single user shell on the console
if ! sulogin $CONSOLE
then
    log_failure_msg "Attempt to start maintenance shell failed. 
Continuing with system boot in 5 seconds."
    sleep 5
fi
```

It's the [`sulogin`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sulogin) that does it in this case.